# Printing multiple ng-repeat elements in a single row

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list of item and ng-repeat display them in the page. Below is the simplified structure -

```
[   
  {
    "id": "elem-1",
    "position": {
      "row": 1,
      "column": 1
     }   
  },
  {
    "id": "elem-2",
    "position": {
      "row": 2,
      "column": 1
     }   
  },
  {
    "id": "elem-3",
    "position": {
      "row": 2,
      "column": 2
     }   
  }    
]
```

Now elem-1 should come in first row, while the second row should have elem-2 and elem-3, side-by-side. I have checked ng-repeat-start and also gone through the existing similar topics in Stack overflow but not sure how to do this. This is my HTML template

```
<div layout="row" ng-repeat="item in inputElemAll">
    <div ng-if="if the current row has 1 column">
        <md-input-container class="md-block">
            <!-- Print the element-->
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div ng-if="if current row has more than 1 column">
        <md-input-container class="md-block" flex="33">
            <!-- Print the element-->
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

All I'm trying here is to add a flex attribute in case I have to show more columns in a single row. But the problem is, with every ng-repeat a new <div> with "row" layout is started and I'm stuck here. Not sure how to access multiple ng-repeat elements and also be on the same <div> simultaneously.

P.S. I use [material layout](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/introduction), in case you are interested.

Comment: show us your html plz

Comment: you also have to sort?

Comment: yes...i sort based on row, if row is same, i sort based on column

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you wanna show your array like a table and maximum rows/columns are not greater than length of your array. You have to use two loops with `ng-repeat`, first one is for all rows and seconds one is for columns. also use 'orderBy' to sort. I mixed your json array and the result is as expected:

```
 <div layout="row" ng-repeat="row in inputElemAll">
      <div ng-repeat="item in inputElemAll | orderBy:'position.column'">
        <div ng-if="$parent.$index==item.position.row-1">
              <md-input-container class="md-block">
                  {{item.id}}
              </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>  
  </div>
```

Check this jsFiddle working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/hd1by95r/47/

Comment: Simple and elegant...fixed my issue. Thanks.

Comment: you are welcome! accept the answer for further usage :)